# Error: Invalid hook call on tRPC and Mantine CSS Custom hook

Tags: typescript, forms, next.js, arrow-functions, trpc.io

I'm having a `Unhandled Runtime Error` on Next.js. Calling an arrow function with void type was not a problem. I made it before implementing useForm hook on Mantine CSS library.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Here is the code.

```js
import {
  Container,
  Input,
  Text,
  Flex,
  ActionIcon,
  ScrollArea,
  TextInput,
} from '@mantine/core'
import { useForm } from '@mantine/form'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { api } from '~/utils/api'
import { HiTrash } from 'react-icons/hi'

const TodoApp = () => {
  const form = useForm({
    initialValues: {
      title: '',
    },
  })

  const { data: sessionData } = useSession()

  const { data: tasks, refetch: refetchTasks } = api.task.getAll.useQuery(
    undefined,
    { enabled: sessionData?.user !== undefined }
  )

  const createTask = (values: { title: string }) => {
    return api.task.create
      .useMutation({ onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks() })
      .mutate({
        title: values.title,
        recursion: {},
        analytics: {},
        reminder: {},
        taskSequence: {},
      })
  }

  const deleteTask = api.task.delete.useMutation({
    onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks(),
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Container my={64} px={32} bg='gray.8' h='80vh' w='40rem'>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.onSubmit(values => {
            console.log(values)
            createTask(values)
          })}
        >
          <TextInput
            py={64}
            placeholder='Add Your Task Here.'
            {...form.getInputProps('title')}
          />
        </form>
        <ScrollArea h={400}>
          <Flex gap='md' justify='flex-start' direction='column'>
            {tasks?.map(task => (
              <Flex
                key={task.id}
                justify='space-between'
                bg='pink.9'
                p={8}
                sx={{ borderRadius: '0.4rem' }}
              >
                <Text fw={700} c='white'>
                  {task.title}
                </Text>
                <ActionIcon color='grape' variant='transparent'>
                  <HiTrash
                    size='1.5rem'
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteTask.mutate({ id: task.id })
                    }}
                  />
                </ActionIcon>
              </Flex>
            ))}
          </Flex>
        </ScrollArea>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default TodoApp
```

I was able to add data on my db using this version.

```js
import {
  Container,
  Input,
  Box,
  Text,
  Button,
  Flex,
  ActionIcon,
  ScrollArea,
} from '@mantine/core'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { api } from '~/utils/api'
import { HiTrash } from 'react-icons/hi'
import type { BaseSyntheticEvent } from 'react'

const TodoApp = () => {
  const { data: sessionData } = useSession()

  const { data: tasks, refetch: refetchTasks } = api.task.getAll.useQuery(
    undefined,
    { enabled: sessionData?.user !== undefined }
  )

  const createTask = api.task.create.useMutation({
    onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks(),
  })

  const deleteTask = api.task.delete.useMutation({
    onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks(),
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Container my={64} px={32} bg='gray.8' h='80vh' w='40rem'>
        <Input
          py={64}
          placeholder='Add Your Task Here.'
          onKeyDown={e => {
            if (e.currentTarget.value.length < 1) return
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              createTask.mutate({
                title: e.currentTarget.value,
                recursion: {},
                analytics: {},
                reminder: {},
                taskSequence: {},
              })
              e.currentTarget.value = ''
            }
          }}
        />
        <ScrollArea h={400}>
          <Flex gap='md' justify='flex-start' direction='column'>
            {tasks?.map(task => (
              <Flex
                key={task.id}
                justify='space-between'
                bg='pink.9'
                p={8}
                sx={{ borderRadius: '0.4rem' }}
              >
                <Text fw={700} c='white'>
                  {task.title}
                </Text>
                <ActionIcon color='grape' variant='transparent'>
                  <HiTrash
                    size='1.125rem'
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteTask.mutate({ id: task.id })
                    }}
                  />
                </ActionIcon>
              </Flex>
            ))}
          </Flex>
        </ScrollArea>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default TodoApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating call methods of .useMutation and .mutate helped. I don't know why.

```js
...
  const createTask = api.task.create.useMutation({
    onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks(),
  })

  const createTaskValues = (values: { title: string }) =>
    createTask.mutate({
      title: values.title,
      recursion: {},
      analytics: {},
      reminder: {},
      taskSequence: {},
    })

  const deleteTask = api.task.delete.useMutation({
    onSuccess: async () => await refetchTasks(),
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Container my={64} px={32} bg='gray.8' h='80vh' w='40rem'>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.onSubmit(values => {
            if (form.values.title.length <= 0) return
            console.log(values)
            createTaskValues(values)
            form.values.title = ''
          })}
        >
          <TextInput
            py={64}
            placeholder='Add Your Task Here.'
            {...form.getInputProps('title')}
          />
        </form>
...
```